# How nametests and meaww fetch friends which is not available from graph 2.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to fetch friends profile pics of a logged in user.From Graph 2.0, userfriends permission will fetch only the users who are using the app. However, I am surprised to see nametests and meaww apps are fetching friends profile pics, I see they are asking just email, publicprofile, userposts and friendslist permissions.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume they are using taggable_friends or invitable_friends which Facebook will only allow to be used after submitting for reviews. [Link for submitting to facebook for approval](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/) Both these apps are something that increases user engagement and activity in Facebook so Facebook will approve this to developers that look promising and well designed.

Comment: It is unlikely that Facebook approved this for the apps in question. Those endpoints are for tagging or inviting friends only, and nothing else – including explicitly not for any “but my app needs all of the user’s friends” scenarios. If those apps in question actually got this approved, then most likely they cheated by presenting different functionality to the reviewer.

Comment: @CBroe I don't know how they got approved but these apps makes a lot of engagement in users especially teenagers who are new to Facebook,its really important for Facebook to have new users getting engaged constantly.Trust me even if the reviewers haven't approved them when zuckerberg see this he will give direct command to approve them.Trust me he have studied human phsycology,and more over these sites have 27million users/day.Not some kids play we are talking about